# Quiz scoring algorithm for how close an answer is

Tags: algorithm, math

I am trying to generate a small algorithm that will give a user a decimal score out of 1 based on how close their answer is to a true answer. These answers will always be numeric and be things like 'How many x did this?'
I will be setting a sensible maximum and minimum value for each answer where if a users answer exceeds this, they will score nothing though am a bit stuck on getting an equation created ...
As an example, a correct answer could be 100 and a sensible minimum could be set as 50. A user specifying 75 would thus be given a score of 0.5

Perhaps getting a bit complicated now but it would also be nice to allocate the score on a curve so the result is not linear and thus weighting is higher the nearer you are to the correct answer

Any help or better ideas for this scoring would be much appreciated

Comment: Why negative vote? Anyways, you are looking for a special case of `Grading on a curve`. Calculate `Mean`, `Standard Deviation` and then calculate the percentage. [Check out this work](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Wikitexts/UC_Davis/UCD_Chem_2C/UCD_Chem_2C%3A_Larsen/Readings,_Reviews,_and_Grading/Grading_on_a_Curve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted the scoring to be non-linear (to reward closeness to the answer) you could try a 'squared difference' formula. E.g.

```
score = 1 - (abs((answer - input)/(answer - minimum)))^2
```

e.g. with correct = 100, minimum = 60, answer = 70 you would get:

```
score = 1 - (abs((100 - 70)/(100 - 60)))^2 = 0.4375
```

If you want to give a greater reward for closeness, you could use a higher power. Note that division by zero will occur if answer = minimum.

Answer (score 2):

A formula code could be like this :

> score = abs(input - answer) / (answer - min)

for your example we have `input = 75` , `answer = 100` and `min = 50` so:

> score = abs(75 - 100) / (100 - 50) = 25 / 50 = 0.5

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is perfect for the linear answer

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the algorithm in Java and made a small test case.

```
public class Quiz{

    public static double calculateScore(int input, 
                                        int correctAnswer, 
                                        int minimumAnswer){

        if(input == correctAnswer){
            return 1;
        }

        double correctInterval = Math.abs(correctAnswer - minimumAnswer);
        double relativeAnswer = Math.abs(correctAnswer - input);


        if(relativeAnswer > correctInterval){
            return 0;
        }else{
            double score = relativeAnswer/correctInterval;

            score *= score;// make ^2 to avoid a linear progression

            return 1.0 - score;
        }
    }
}


public class QuizTest{

    @Test
    public void testCalculateScore() {

        assertTrue(0 == Quiz.calculateScore(5, 20, 15));
        assertTrue(0 == Quiz.calculateScore(30, 20, 15));
        assertTrue(1 == Quiz.calculateScore(20, 20, 15));
        assertTrue(0 < Quiz.calculateScore(17, 20, 15));
        assertTrue(0 < Quiz.calculateScore(22, 20, 15));
        assertTrue(Quiz.calculateScore(18, 20, 15) == Quiz.calculateScore(22, 20, 15));

        assertTrue(Quiz.calculateScore(17, 20, 15) < Quiz.calculateScore(22, 20, 15));
    }
}
```

The test run is successful

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks to be a nice implementation of Geddes formula

Comment: It's coincidently the same algorithm. It just took some time to wirte the jave classes, so i didn't see his answer in time.